# Check if touchend in a particular div is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

I have 6 DIVs. Each one of them has a corresponding `touchstart` and `touchend` block of codes. However, If I touch them all, and release them all at once, the `touchend` event of all the DIVs fire. What I want is, if at least one of the DIVs fire the `touchend` event in them, the other `touchend` event of the other DIVs will not fire. I can give you my code if you need it. I am new to Web Technologies

**EDIT**

Here is my code. Sorry its a little bit repetitive.

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var ktr = 6;
var apple01Show,apple02Show,apple03Show,lemon01Show,lemon02Show,lemon03Show;
var apple01Release,apple02Release,apple03Release,lemon01Release,lemon02Release,lemon03Release;

function startGame(){
        clearTimeout(apple01Show);
        clearTimeout(apple02Show);
        clearTimeout(apple03Show);
        clearTimeout(lemon01Show);
        clearTimeout(lemon02Show);
        clearTimeout(lemon03Show);
        clearTimeout(apple01Release);
        clearTimeout(apple02Release);
        clearTimeout(apple03Release);
        clearTimeout(lemon01Release);
        clearTimeout(lemon01Release);
        clearTimeout(lemon01Release);
        console.log(array.length +' array length');
        if(ktr < 1){
            //activate div of logo
            $('#logo').show();
            setTimeout(function (){
                restart();
                disableAllTouches();
                startGame();
                array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]; //, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
                ktr = 6;
                $('#logo').hide();
            },1000);
        }else

        shuffle(array);
        if(typeof array[0] == 'undefined'){
            //activate div of logo
            $('#logo').show();
            setTimeout(function (){
                restart();
                disableAllTouches();
                startGame();
                array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]; //, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
                ktr = 6;
                $('#logo').hide();
            },1000);
        }
        console.log(array);
        console.log(array[0]);

        switch(array[0]){
        case 0: //greenApple01
            console.log('greenApple01');

            apple01Show = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#apple01').show();
            },200)
            $('#greenApple01').show();

            console.log('randomnumber: '+array[0] +' greenApple01');
            $("#apple01").on('touchstart', function(){
                console.log(ktr+' ktr');
                console.log(array);
                console.log('value of array at greenApple01: '+array);
                array.splice(0,1);
                startGame();
                ktr--;
            }).on('touchend', function(){
                apple01Release = setTimeout(function (){
                    console.log('released greenApple01');
                    restart(); //hide all elements
                    disableAllTouches();
                    array.length = 0;
                    array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
                    ktr = 6;
                    startGame(); //spawn them again
                },1000);
            });
            break;
        case 1: // greenApple02
            console.log('greenApple02');

            apple02Show = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#apple02').show();
            },200);
            //$('#apple01').show();
            $('#greenApple02').show();

            console.log('randomnumber: '+array[0] +' greenApple01');
            $("#apple02").on('touchstart', function(){
                console.log(ktr+' ktr');
                console.log(array);
                array.splice(0,1);
                console.log('value of array at greenApple02: '+array);
                startGame();
                ktr--;
            }).on('touchend', function(){
                apple02Release = setTimeout(function (){
                    console.log('released greenApple02');
                    restart();
                    disableAllTouches();
                    array.length = 0;
                    array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
                    ktr = 6;
                    startGame();
                },1000);
            });
            break;
        case 2: // greenLemon01
            console.log('greenLemon01');

            lemon01Show = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#lemon01').show();
            },200);
            $('#greenLemon01').show();
            console.log('randomnumber: '+array[0] +' greenLemon01');
            $("#lemon01").on('touchstart', function(){

                console.log(ktr+' ktr');
                console.log(array);
                array.splice(0,1);
                console.log('value of array at greenLemon01: '+array);
                startGame();
                ktr--;
            }).on('touchend', function(){
                lemon01Release = setTimeout(function (){
                    console.log('released greenLemon01');
                    restart();
                    disableAllTouches();
                    array.length = 0;
                    array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
                    ktr = 6;
                    startGame();
                },1000);
            });
            break;
        case 3: // greenLemon02
            console.log('greenLemon02');
            lemon02Show = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#lemon02').show();
            },200);
            $('#greenLemon02').show();
            console.log('randomnumber: '+array[0] +' greenLemon02');
            $("#lemon02").on('touchstart', function(){
                console.log(ktr+' ktr');
                console.log(array);
                array.splice(0,1);
                console.log('value of array at greenLemon02: '+array);
                startGame();
                ktr--;
            }).on('touchend', function(){
                lemon02Release = setTimeout(function (){
                    console.log('released greenLemon02');
                    restart();
                    disableAllTouches();
                    array.length = 0;
                    array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
                    ktr = 6;
                    startGame();
                },1000);
            });
            break;
        case 4: // redLemon02
            console.log('redLemon02');
            lemon03Show = setTimeout(function () {
                $('.lemon03').show();
            },200);
            $('#redLemon02').show();
            console.log('randomnumber: '+array[0] +' redLemon02');
            $(".lemon03").on('touchstart', function(){
                console.log(ktr+' ktr');
                console.log(array);
                array.splice(0,1);
                console.log('value of array at redLemon02: '+array);
                startGame();
                ktr--;
            }).on('touchend', function(){
                lemon03Release = setTimeout(function (){
                    console.log('released redLemon02');
                    restart();
                    disableAllTouches();
                    array.length = 0;
                    array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
                    ktr = 6;
                    startGame();
                },1000);
            });
            break;
        case 5: // yellowApple03
            console.log('yellowApple03');
            apple03Show = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#apple03').show();
            },200);
            $('#yellowApple03').show();
            console.log('randomnumber: '+array[0] +' yellowApple03');
            $("#apple03").on('touchstart', function(){
                console.log(ktr+' ktr');
                console.log(array);
                array.splice(0,1);
                console.log('value of array at yellowApple03: '+array);
                startGame();
                ktr--;
            }).on('touchend', function(){
                apple03Release = setTimeout(function (){
                    console.log('released yellowApple03');
                    restart();
                    disableAllTouches();
                    array.length = 0;
                    array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
                    ktr = 6;
                    startGame();
                },1000);
            });
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    }
```

My three functions: function 1:

```
function shuffle(array) {
          var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

          // While there remain elements to shuffle...
          while (0 !== currentIndex) {

            // Pick a remaining element...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
          }

          return array;
    }
```

Function 2:

```
function restart(){
        $("#greenApple01").hide();
        $("#greenApple02").hide();
        $("#greenLemon01").hide();
        $("#greenLemon02").hide();
        $("#redLemon02").hide();
        $("#yellowApple03").hide();
        $('#apple01').hide();
        $('#apple02').hide();
        $('#apple03').hide();
        $('#lemon01').hide();
        $('#lemon02').hide();
        $('#lemon03').hide();
        $("#logo").hide();
    }
```

Function 3:

```
function disableAllTouches(){
        $('#apple01').off('touchstart');
        $('#apple02').off('touchstart');
        $('#apple03').off('touchstart');
        $('#lemon01').off('touchstart');
        $('#lemon02').off('touchstart');
        $('.lemon03').off('touchstart');
    }
```

Comment: relevant code is always helpful :)

Comment: I think touchend is behaving sensibly. If you want to ignore the other touchends, then you should write code to set some flag when the first one comes in and ignore the rest if the flag is set.

Comment: Why is someone voted to close my question? Sorry if my question is for newbees.

Comment: could be just a typo, but the last line of function 3 is different :P Also, in your second function, your switching between single quotes and double quotes

Comment: Is there a difference between double quotes and single quotes?

Comment: I made them all single quotes, it still happens. :(